# Convert text with negative number to currency

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a large spreadsheet that I converted from a PDF. One column has numbers that represent dollar values. The negative numbers appear with a trailing dash (or maybe a hyphen), such as 123.45-

I need to convert this column to a usable numerical format. This formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-",X3)),-VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(X3,"-","")),X3)` works on some of the cells but produces a `#VALUE!` error on others.  Any suggestions for an improvement?

Comment: It would be useful to know what differentiates the cells it works on from the ones where it doesn't

Comment: I agree!  But I haven't been able to figure that out.  I tried using the =cell() function but they all were formatted as "General".  Maybe there are some non-printing characters in there, or the characters look the same but aren't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Lambda Formula

```
=BYROW(X3:X1000,
   LAMBDA(r, 
     IFERROR(IF(FIND("-",r,LEN(r)-2)>0,
               ("-"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(r,"-","")," ",""))/1,),
             r)))
```

##### Single Row Formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND("-",X3,LEN(X3)-2)>0,
           ("-"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(X3,"-","")," ",""))/1,),
         X3)
```

##### All Values are "Numbers"

If everything in the column you are checking should be a either a positive or negative number, then the following modified code would be better.

The differences from the LAMBDA formula are that the `FIND` function character limit is removed, a `SUBSTITUTE` function was added to strip spaces from positive values, and the positive strings are also coerced to numbers as required.

```
=BYROW(X3:X1000,
    LAMBDA(r,
       IFERROR(IF(FIND("-",r)>0,
              ("-"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(r,"-","")," ",""))/1,),
       SUBSTITUTE(r," ","")/1)))
```

##### Code Comments

---

```
1   =IFERROR(IF(FIND("-",r,LEN(r)-2)>0,
2              ("-"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(r,"-","")," ",""))/1,),
3            r)
```

| Line | Comments |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | `FIND` limits the search to the last two characters only `LEN(r)-2` to avoid false positives while still overcoming a trailing space. Given your knowledge of the data involved, you could loosen that (eg. `LEN(r)-4`) or remove the limit entirely `FIND("-",r)` as you deem appropriate. The formula is wrapped in `IFERROR` to handle any errors when <kbd>-</kbd> is not found and return the original value `r` (Line #3) instead. |
| **2** | The old value is stripped of all <kbd>-</kbd> and spaces using nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions and a <kbd>-</kbd> is then prepended to it. A math calculation is then applied to the resulting string to coerce it into a number. `/1` was used in this case. |
| **3** | Just the value passed back if <kbd>-</kbd> not found (`IFFERROR` on Line #1) |

[image]

Comment: Best explanation I've every seen on this site!  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it was useful. 